# Bash if [ -d $1] returning true for empty $1

Tags: bash, if-statement

So I have the following little script and keep wondering..

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d $1 ]; then
  echo 'foo'
else
  echo 'bar'
fi
```

.. why does this print foo when called *without arguments*? How is it that the test [-d ] returns true for an empty string?

Comment: `if [ -d "$1" ]; then echo 'foo'; fi` will not print `foo` when `$1` is empty, but it doesn't answer your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From: [`info coreutils 'test invocation'`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/test-invocation.html) (reference found through `man test`):

> If EXPRESSION is omitted, `test' returns false.  **If EXPRESSION is a
>   single argument,`test' returns false if the argument is null and true
>   otherwise**.  The argument can be any string, including strings like
>   `-d',`-1', `--',`--help', and `--version' that most other programs
>   would treat as options.  To get help and version information, invoke
>   the commands`[ --help' and `[ --version', without the usual closing
>   brackets.

Highlighting properly:

> If EXPRESSION is a single argument, `test' returns false if the
>   argument is null and true otherwise

So whenever we do `[ something ]` it will return `true` if that `something` is not null:

```
$ [ -d ] && echo "yes"
yes
$ [ -d "" ] && echo "yes"
$ 
$ [ -f  ] && echo "yes"
yes
$ [ t ] && echo "yes"
yes
```

Seeing the second one `[ -d "" ] && echo "yes"` returning false, you get the way to solve this issue: quote `$1` so that `-d` always gets a parameter:

```
if [ -d "$1" ]; then
  echo 'foo'
else
  echo 'bar'
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason is plain and simple:  The syntax does not match the case in which the `-d` is recognized as an operator working on a file name.  It is just taken as a string, and each non-empty string is true.  Only if a second parameter to `-d` is given, it is recognized as the operator to find out whether a given FILE is a directory.

The same applies to all the other operators like `-e`, `-r`, etc.

In your case, use double quotes to avoid running into that "problem":

```
[ -d "$1" ]
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason that

```
[ -d ] && echo y
```

produces `y` is that the shell interprets it as a *string* in the `test` command and evaluates it to true.  Even saying:

```
[ a ] && echo y
```

would produce `y`.  Quoting from `help test`:

```
 string        True if string is not the null string.
```

---

That is why quoting variables is recommended.  Saying:

```
[ -d "$1" ] && echo y
```

should not produce `y` when called without arguments.